# Difference between using and obj and direct constructor in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, object, constructor

Suppose I have a class named `ABC'

```
Class ABC:IDisposable
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string Method1()
    {
    // Implements 
    }
    //end of class
}
```

I hear from other's  that you should use always inherit `IDisposable` to free memory creating object of above class like this:

```
using(ABC objABC = new ABC())
{
  objABC.Method1();
}
```

but there is other ways to call and use above class and methods for E.g.

```
private string testmethods()
{
    ABC objABC = new ABC();
    string test =  objABC.Method1();
    // I want to know this above `objABC` 's memory is free after finish `testmethods()`?
    // we can also call using this like below
    string test2 = new ABC().Method1();
}
```

I want to know which is the best way to achieve this?

I also want to know is, is that Object memory automatically cleared after end of `testmethods()` calls ?

Comment: `using` block is a handy way to call `Dispose` method (not always it means freeing resources), but you don't have to use it always. It is here to make your life easier

Comment: _"my senior says that you should use always inherit IDisposable to free memory"_ - is your senior a self-proclaimed senior? That remark only already screams [cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: To be honest, after editing this a few times, I noticed a lot of discrepancies with the code.... please double check before posting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Disposable pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx) exists to free up **unmanaged** resources. So unless your C# program calls some native API, or uses classes which themselves implement the Disposable pattern, having your class implement IDisposable and always handling it with `using` is completely pointless.

Comment: It's also used to free managed resources (== wrapped unmanaged resources).

Comment: so, if I inherit `IDisposable`  I dont need to use `using` block right ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, but that is what JanDoerrenhaus said. When a native class has unmanaged resources it should implement IDisposable already.

Comment: And you also use it to unhook event handlers to avoid resource leaks.

Comment: @AnantDabhi `using` is just convenience code for an automatic `Dispose` call. So either your class implements `IDisposable`, then you should handle it with `using`, or it doesn't implement `IDisposable`, then you cannot handle it with `using`.

Comment: hmm tested it means I cant use` using` block  if I not Inherit `IDisposable ` or `Implemented` `IDisposed`

Comment: Yes, that is what I said. "So either your class implements `IDisposable`, then you should handle it with `using`, or it doesn't implement `IDisposable`, then you cannot handle it with `using`"

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `ABC` does not hold on to any unmanaged resources, it does not need to implement `IDisposable`. Objects in C# are eligible for garbage collection as soon as there are no live references to them, and when the garbage collector runs, the memory they use will be freed automatically.

Your classes should only need to implement `IDisposable` if they own unmanaged resources that need to be freed, or own other managed objects which implement `IDisposable`. If your classes hold unmanaged resources, they should also implement a [finalizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) to free them if `Dispose` is not called before they are collected.

Therefore, the second method is preferred and `objABC` is eligible for collection after `objABC.Method1` has returned (actually it may be collected sooner although this is an internal GC mechanism). Note that it will not automatically be freed at that point, but only when the GC next runs, assuming there are no more references to it.

Answer (score 2):

IDisposable interface is designed for supporting Disposable pattern which is used to explicitly free *other than memory resources*: since Garbage Collector (GC) could do with memory only, other resources such that open files, database connections, various unmanaged
resources etc. should be closed explicitly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx

The typical scheme of using IDisposable is

```
  // MyResourceWrapper is IDisposable
  using (MyResourceWrapper wrapper = new MyResourceWrapper()) { // <- acquire resource
    ... // <- work with resource
  } // <- free resource
```

For instance

```
  String text;

  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\MyText.txt")) { // resource (file stream) opened
    text = sr.ReadToEnd(); // <- resource (file stream) utilized (read)
  } // <- resource freed (file stream closed)
```

when you don't have any resource(s) to be freed within your class, you have no need of IDisposable to be implemented

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself first - Would you write a try-finally block on the second code section in your question? If yes, then what would you write in the finally block? If your ABC class is using an unmanaged resource, and It implements the IDisposable interface, then you would have called Dispose method in the finally block.

```
using(ABC objABC = new ABC())
{
  objABC.Method1();
}
```

is equivalent of this :-

```
ABC objABC = new ABC()
try
{
   objABC.Method1();
}
finally
{
   objABC..Dispose()
}
```

So now, If you don't have anything unmanaged to dispose in class ABC, why would you implement IDisposable interface on this class?

An example of class with unmanaged resources is SqlConnection which implements IDisposable and in Its Dispose method It disposes all those unmanaged resources. That's why you see people using code like following :-

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
...........
}
```

Comment: hmm that's really helpful information ..I stuck in garbage and othes things so, I no think about unamaged code ..

Comment: @AnantDabhi - Upvote If you find this useful. :-)